# Prevent multiple executions of same listener

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a chrome extension. I have a a listener on `chrome.tabs.onUpdate` event. On this listener i call a function that modifies an instance of a class that should model the window where the update happened.

**Problem:** the function called in the listener is async and multiple modifications happens in sequence before the first call is finished and that generates undesirable resutls;

Here is a simplified example that illustrates the situation.

```js
var obj = new MyClass();

async function modifyObj( windowId, tabId, changeInfo ){
    // modify object (X)
    var window = await new Promise( (resolve,reject) => {
        chrome.windows.get(windowId, {populate: true}, (w) => resolve(w));
    });
   // modify object (Y)
}

chrome.tabs.onUpdate.addListener( (tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
    modifyObj(tab.windowId, tab.id, changeInfo);
});
```

Lets say 3 tabs got updates in sequence (like when you open 3 tabs at the same time from your bookmarks)

Executions runs something like follows

1. Tab 1 updated

   - anonymous listener
   - `modifyObject` until `await`
2. Tab 2 updated

   - anonymous listener
   - `modifyObject` until `await`
3. Tab 3 updated

   - anonymous listener
   - `modifyObject` until `await`
4. `await` calls gets resolved in some order and then the rest of `modifyObject` is executed

Up to `await` the code marked with `modify object (X)` is run multiple times before the first execution of `modifyObject` is done. For various reason, in the original code, that can't happen. The code on `modify object (Y)` is strictly dependent on the modifications made in `modify object (X)`.

What i want is:

1. Tab 1 updated

   - anonymous listener
   - `modifyObject` until `await`
   - execute rest of the function
2. Tab 2 updated

   - anonymous listener
   - `modifyObject` until `await`
   - execute rest of the function
3. Tab 3 updated

   - anonymous listener
   - `modifyObject` until `await`
   - execute rest of the function

But, of course, we have no control over when chrome will fire up the listeners.

What are effective and simple ways of accomplishing this?

Comment: Do you want each execution of `modifyObj` to run to the end before another call of the function starts its `// modify object (X)` part?

Comment: Yes. The whole `modifyObject()` should run as a single operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have each call of `modifyObj` chain off of a *previous* call of the function so that no more than one call is in progress at a time:

```
const obj = new MyClass();
let modifyProm = Promise.resolve();
async function modifyObj( windowId, tabId, changeInfo ){
    // modify object (X)
    var window = await new Promise( (resolve,reject) => {
        chrome.windows.get(windowId, {populate: true}, (w) => resolve(w));
    });
   // modify object (Y)
}

chrome.tabs.onUpdate.addListener( (tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
    modifyProm = modifyProm.then(() => modifyObj(tab.windowId, tab.id, changeInfo));
});
```

Comment: This is so simple i don't know how i didn't thought that. I was searching about locks, mutexes and stuff heh :)